# XM Cloud locally with docker compose gives: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: docker, xm-cloud

I have XM Cloud running locally in a docker container. This means with self-signed certificates.

When I use JSS to create and deploy the JSS Style guide application, I keep getting the following error when starting my JSS application on http://localhost:3000: **FetchError: request to https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate**

[image]

With the built-in GraphiQL explorer on URL https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge/ui I can execute GraphQL queries on the endpoint https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge.

This does not work with [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) offline GraphQL API client, I get the following error

[image: Insomnia error]

When I disable **validate certificates** in the settings of Insomnia it works:

[image: Insomnia settings]

I tried to set the environment variable `ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED "0"` in the `Dockerfile` for the CM server, but that did not help.

Any ideas to get this working in an docker containers based environment with self-signed certificates?

Comment: Can you include texts from your screenshots as code blocks? That helps with SEO and therefore helps others to find your question and answer.

Comment: You really should be using the docker hosted rendering host for this. Then you wouldn't get any certificate errors. Did you use the XM Cloud Starter template to create your starting repo?

Answer (score 2):

Ah blizz! I shouldn't set the environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `0` on the XM Cloud CM server (in the Docker container), but on my dev machine where I run `jss start:connected`. Now it works!!

Comment: Once you added `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to your environment variables did you then encounter another issue where the site displays correctly but shows errors stating that the CPD `"clientKey" is required`?